# Spring-jms. How to customize broker url for rabbitmq?

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, rabbitmq, spring-jms

All examples I read related with activeMq and spring-boot has especial property to change the url of broker:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=<SOME_URL>
```

By default it uses default settings: default url and default port.
But I use rabbirMq and I want to know how to change broker url

I've read [this one](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-rabbitmq)

I've added `application.properties` to the `src/main/resources`
with following content(host absolutely wrong, I expected to see error):

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=olololo
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

But it doesn't affect application.
Looks like spring(boot) doesn't read these prioerties.

### P.S.

Project structure looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot does not have auto configuration support for rabbitmq-jms (the link you referenced is the native RabbitMQ AMQP auto configuration).

For the JMS connection factory, you will have to do the configuration yourself...

```
@Bean
public RMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host}") String host,
        @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port}") int port) {
    RMQConnectionFactory cf = new RMQConnectionFactory();
    cf.setHost(host);
    cf.setPort(port);
    return cf;
}
```

Comment: If write wrong url - app prints: **Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'my_queue_new' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: ololo**

Comment: So don't "write" the wrong URL :) What do you expect?

Comment: All right despite the fact I expected application won't start(could not load bean from context or something like this). I believe developers had arguments to make it so.

Comment: That's how spring-jms handles connection problems.

Comment: As I understand I can replace DefaultMessageListenerContainer with my own implementation of AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer

Comment: You could also provide your own bean that implements `SmartLifecycle` and try to create a connection in the `start()` method; if that throws an exception, the application won't load.